# (Visual C++) Get PID From Thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-c++, pid

I'm trying to track a certain applications behaviour, I've grabbed the visible thread that draws the Window, having that thread is there any way to determine the process it belongs to?

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId() will tell you *both*.  GetProcessIdOfThread() is what you ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetProcessIdOfThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683216%28VS.85%29.aspx) api for newer versions of windows.

For older versions you have to find it manually using the ToolHelp library functions [Thread32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686728%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[Thread32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686731%28VS.85%29.aspx) searching for the threadid and getting the process id from the THREADENTRY32 structure.

Comment: Does the Thread32First/Thread32Next solution apply to all platforms? To use GetProcessIdOfThread it's necessary to have a HANDLE to the thread, but OpenThread() fails when THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION is set..

Comment: thread32xx will work on all platforms. I assume OpenThread is failing because it's a protected process, you may need to use THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION instead.